Powershell, trying to compare data sets efficiently
I have 2 data sets. Set1 has roughly 129k lines, has an ID column and, importantly, has the 2nd column code, which I will need later. Set2 has only has the ID column. Set2 also has about 83k lines, which should all be within Set1. Both files/datasets should be in order by ID, if that matters. Both should be as strings, but all IDs are padded to 10 digits long.

Set 1:

ID,Code
0000000002,0
0000012345,1
0000023456,0
0000056789,1
0000034567,0
0000078908,1


Set 2:

0000000002
0000012345
0000056789
0000034567

I am trying to find all IDs within Set1 that are not in Set2, including that 2nd column for each ID from dataset 1. I also need all IDs within Set1 that are in Set2, also including that 2nd column for each ID.
I also need subsets for each of those:

All IDs within Set1 that are not in Set2, including that code column, separated by the code 0,1,2.

All IDs within Set1 that are in Set2, including that code column, separated by the code 0,1,2.


The main issues I am having are the fact that the datasets are mismatched in that the main dataset has 2 columns, and the comparing dataset only has 1. And the fact that the datasets are so large, that I am trying to do this efficiently so it doesn't take a large amount of time, since this is a daily running program, and has other things to run after I get these subset lists.

I have tried to import as arrays and compare them to get the sets of data I need, but it takes WAY too long to be practical. I am talking like 1 hour+. that is not even getting to the point that I need to subset them based on the 2nd column.
$IDsNotIn2 = $Array1 | Where {$Array2 -NotContains $_}


I have tried to use hashtables, and could not get the compares to work. I imported the csv's as hashtables. Then called Compare-Object. They returned nothing / showed nothing when called.
import-CSV -Path $FILE_LOC | ForEach-Object { $hashtable1[$_.ID] = $_.Code }

import-CSV -Path $FIXED_FILE_LOC -Header ID | ForEach-Object { $hashtable2[$_.ID] }

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $hashtable1 -DifferenceObject $hashtable2 -Property ID -PassThru | ? {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty SideIndicator

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $hashtable1 -DifferenceObject $hashtable2


I have tried .GetEnumerator and iterating over the first hashtable and if the key exists in the 2nd, creating a 3nd table with the new values. But for whatever reason, all the values from the first table get put into the new table.
$hashtable1.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
IF (-Not ($hashtable2.ContainsKey($_.key))){
    $ID = $_.key
    $columncode = $_.value
    $ID_Not_in_First_File[$ID] = @{
     $Code= $columncode 
        }
    }
}




Can you edit your question copy pasting a literal sample of both sets including the headers if they have any?

I can't put a literal sample of my datasets, not really. The data sets are exactly like my sample I put in the OG question. Dataset 1 is a CSV file with headers like ID,code, but otherwise it is exactly like I put in there. 10 digit numbers, a comma and then a 0,1,2. Dataset 2 is literally just a 10 digit number per line, no headers.

right, that's clear now, what I meant is you have Set1= and Set2= in your question and then each line has space padding and I'm assuming that's not the case (there is no space padding). This is confusing for readers of your question

Okay I understand now. I used that as psuedocode, not really meaning anything but identifying the sets. I have changed that.

In general I would make a hashtable of one of the lists.

I was trying to make a hash of both lists and trying to compare them. But the solution that Santiago proposed was making a hash of one and looping over the other, which is what helped me and I was able to use that to solve my problem. Thank you.

If I understand correctly, an efficient solution can be the following:
$mapNotInSet2 = @{}
$mapInSet2 = @{}
$rowsNotInSet2 = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
# NOTE: Use absolute path to the file here,
#       don't use relative path when calling a .NET method
$set2 = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
    [System.IO.File]::ReadLines('path\to\set2.txt'))

$rowsInSet2 = foreach ($row in Import-Csv 'path\to\set1.csv') {
    # Id exists in Set 2
    if ($set2.Contains($row.Id)) {
        if (-not $mapInSet2.ContainsKey($row.Id)) {
            $mapInSet2[$row.Id] = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
        }
        $mapInSet2[$row.Id].Add($row.code)
        $row
        continue
    }

    # else, Id does not exist in Set 2
    if (-not $mapNotInSet2.ContainsKey($row.Id)) {
        $mapNotInSet2[$row.Id] = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
    }
    $mapNotInSet2[$row.Id].Add($row.code)
    $rowsNotInSet2.Add($row)
}

$rowsInSet2

This would produce 4 different outputs, using the sample data:

$rowsInSet2

ID         code
--         ----
0000000002 0
0000012345 1
0000012345 2
0000056789 1
0000034567 0


$mapInSet2 (subset, unique IDs with their corresponding code)

Name                           Value
----                           -----
0000034567                     {0}
0000012345                     {1, 2}
0000056789                     {1}
0000000002                     {0}


$rowsNotInSet2

ID         code
--         ----
0000023456 0
0000078908 1


$mapNotInSet2 (subset, unique IDs with their corresponding code)

Name                           Value
----                           -----
0000078908                     {1}
0000023456                     {0}


Thank you for your help. I found one error in my sample dataset. All IDs should be unique in both lists. eq. There shouldn't be 2 0000012345 in set 1.
Also, I tested your code and I get an error:
  if (-not $mapInSet2.ContainsKey($row.Id)) "Key cannot be null" 

and also at:
  $mapNotInSet2[$row.Id].Add($row.code) "array index evaluated to null".

I have a screenshot of the error, but I don't know how to post it on here.

I just ran again and put $row to print out right before the if statement in the foreach and it is not printing anything out. I changed it to "Write-Output $row" and nothing printed out. I am not sure why it is blank. I am using local files and I even hard coded the direct path "C:\Temp\Z\filename".
I used import-csv on this file before and it worked just fine.

Thank you for your help. I found that I could read in the set1 list, and loop over it as normal. This fixed that issue I was seeing. This helped immensely. Thank you again.
